# split based on the first "-" from the last in a line

Tags: python

I have the below script which basically deletes the sentence after "-",it is breaking when announce.txt contains the below input as it has multiple "-" ,i basically want to split based on the first "-" from the last..please
suggest how to do that...i have hte expected output

INPUT:- //components/rel/bt.wcnss/2.4/wcnss_proc/bt/platform/rom/inc/oi_sbc_tables-generated.h#1 - branch change 700801 (text)

EXPECTED OUTPUT:- //components/rel/bt.wcnss/2.4/wcnss_proc/bt/platform/rom/inc/oi_sbc_tables-generated.h#1

```
f = open('announce.txt', 'r')
z = f.readlines()
f.close()

k = []

for items in z:
    print 'Current item %s'%items
    answer = items.split('-');
    k.append(answer[0].strip() + '\n')

f2 = open('foobar4.txt', 'w')
f2.writelines(k)
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rsplit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

```
"a-b-c-d".rsplit('-',1)

>>> ['a-b-c', 'd']
```

-

```
items = '- //components/rel/bt.wcnss/2.4/wcnss_proc/bt/platform/rom/inc/oi_sbc_tables-generated.h#1 - branch change 700801 (text)'
answer = items.rsplit('-',1);
k.append(answer[0].strip() + '\n')
# print answer[0].strip()
```

Comment: Ha, I knew about `rfind` and `rindex`, but not the right-side `split` dual.  Clearly the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

[`rfind`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind) is your friend.

```
>>> input = '- //components/rel/bt.wcnss/2.4/wcnss_proc/bt/platform/rom/inc/oi_sbc_tables-generated.h#1 - branch change 700801 (text)'
>>> output = input[:input.rfind('-')]
>>> print output
- //components/rel/bt.wcnss/2.4/wcnss_proc/bt/platform/rom/inc/oi_sbc_tables-generated.h#1
```

Known bugs:

- If you don't have that 'comment string', it will happily chop somewhere else (e.g. at `tables-generated`)
- If your string has no dashes at all, it will truncate the input by 1 character (the slicing will be `input[:-1]`)

Comment: can you suggest changes to my script

Answer (score 1):

How about a greedy RegExp:

```
import re
original_string = u'//components/rel/bt.wcnss/2.4/wcnss_proc/bt/platform/rom/inc/oi_sbc_tables-generated.h#1 - branch change 700801 (text)'
match = re.match(r'(.*)-', original_string).groups()
if match:
    new_string = match.groups()[0]
```